# How to specify guest access to C#/SQL internet site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I just created a website in ASP.NET and C# and am hosting it now at this URL below.  This URL is working now:

> http://96.0.101.66/Default.aspx

However, currently this website does not list the SQL tables, which should be on the left-hand side of this window in a gridview.  I think this is because I disabled anonymous access from IIS6 Manager.  (I'm using IIS6 Manager on an XP OS).  I disabled this cause I also have SQL Server 2008 on same machine.  Same machine for hosting website, developing VS 2008 C# code, and SS 2008 database.

However, I see this gridview when I Browse my IIS6 Manager.  So this webpage is working on my computer, just not from the internet.

Which user should I configure to access this website and how?  Like should I choose ASPNET account?  They should be able to append data to existing Adventureworks tables.  They choose which table to append from this URL above.

Also, do I need to upload any MDF files from Adventureworks?  I don't think so cause they should be able to access the Adventureworks database on my computer, right?

I checked Event Viewer and am getting the following Failure Audit:

> Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason:
>   Failed to open the explicitly
>   specified database. [CLIENT: ]

I'm new to IIS and C#, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You probably also want to tell us what you're trying to accomplish. Alternatively, we can download all your code and data and figure it out for ourselves.

Comment: While you're waiting for the URLs, please update your question to tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: how do i upload my code?

Comment: what code do you want to upload? I was joking earlier about downloading all your code. That's because you had your site set so we could do that.

Comment: That's funny, John!  I'm still working on this site.  Thanks for the help--do you live in Nashville?

Comment: No, I don't live in Nashville.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear; please remove that website immediately, it's returning all your pages as it's probably not configured to run IIS. I'd stop that site being public ASAP.

Comment: Thanks Silky.  i just now realize i need to first change my webhosting account to Windows.  This URL should be working in another 10 minutes.